# Is there method to send by not using SMS?

Tags: google, google-messages

I tried to send a message. After that, it displays the following toast:

> SMS is unable.

I can't use SMS. Is there a method to send messages by not using SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Messenger is an SMS/MMS application. If you are not able to send SMS/MMS for some reason, you need to use a different messaging system and a different application. For example, you can use email, or a proprietary service like [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en). If you need your message to arrive as an SMS, you can use a [email-to-SMS gateway](http://mfitzp.io/list-of-email-to-sms-gateways/), though you need to know the carrier used by the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages without using SMS by using a messaging platform. These include
[Google Allo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball),
[Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk),
[Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider),
[Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca),
[Discord](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.discord),
[Kik](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kik.android),
and many more.

If you need your message to arrive as an SMS, you can use
[Google Allo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball).

However, to solve your problem, you might want to try a [factory reset](https://developers.google.com/android/images).